# How to take picture or pick image and Pass to a VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to pass `UIImage` to another `ViewController` using `UIImagePickerController`. User either take a picture and immediately pass it to `ViewController` or select an image from Photo Library then pass it.

I tried following code but didn't work.

```
@IBAction func okButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

  let imageFromSource = UIImagePickerController()
  imageFromSource.delegate = self
  imageFromSource.allowsEditing = false

  imageFromSource.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

  presentViewController(imageFromSource, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

  let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

  dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})

  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let sp = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("photoReady") as! photoReadyScreen

  sp.photoReadyImage.image = selectedImage

  presentViewController(sp, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `photoReadyImage` is outlet to `UIImageView`. If so, you doesn't see your image because when you instantiate your controller outlets is not initialized yet ( = nil ).

To achieve what you want you need to add variable to your `photoReadyScreen` controller:

```
class photoReadyScreen {
...
var pickedPhoto: UIImage?
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  photoReadyImage.image = pickedPhoto
...
```

And replace `sp.photoReadyImage.image = selectedImage` line with `sp.pickedImage = image`.

Also think about using `self.storyboard` instead of creating new one. If you have only one storyboard in your project you don't need to create new - you already have one.

Comment: Indeed, as a general rule you should not mess with another view controller's views. It violates the principle of [**encapsulation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). (And in this particular case it just doesn't work.)

Comment: And in common cases it make app crash. By default outlets from storyboard are unwrapped (e.g. `@IBoutlet var photoReadyImage: UIImageView!`), and when you unwrap `nil` value you get crash.